# Babel does not find a plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

I have an app module and common module that is shared by several app modules.

```
- app
  - src
  - package.json
  - webpack.config.json
  - .babelrc
- common
  - lib
  - package.json
  - .babelrc
```

app/package.json

```
dependencies: {
  common: "../common"
},
devDependencies: {
  ...othe deps,
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
}
```

common/package.json

```
devDependencies: {
  ..other deps,
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
}
```

common code is in es6 and needs to be transpiled in app so webpack.config.js contains

```
{
  test: /\.js/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(ui-common|ui-server-common)\/).*/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
},
```

Everything works fine if I run yarn install in common module, then in app module. That copies complete node_modules of common module so it contains all dev deps including babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.

If I remove node_modules from common module, run yarn install app module, only prod dependencies are copied and babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread is missing in app/node_modules/common/node_modules. I then get

```
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-object-
rest-spread" specified in "/Users/blaf/projects/management-
ui/ui-common/.babelrc" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to 
"/Users/blaf/projects/management-ui/ui-common"
```

because babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread is missing in app/node_modules/common/node_modules. The package is already in app/node_modules so there should be no problem but babel wants it right in the common package? How can I tell babel to use the root level dependency?

Comment: This sounds like expected behavior. Babel looks for plugins relative to the `.babelrc` file, so if they aren't in `common` it won't work.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Babel to look at top level deps? Node.js tries to find dependecy at top level if it's missing in place. Problem is that yarn/npm does dedupe and the plugin ends only at top level.